# I need some advice from Experts on how to develop a PHP site with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, vps

I need some advice from experts :)
I will develop a website using PHP and I will use also MySQL. I bought some server space from a Virtual private server including all the service needed.

How should I develop the site? Shall I develop it on my machine at home (using for example Wamp), and when ready transfer all the files to the server? If so what is the best method to transfer also the database?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What are the criteria for being expert enough to help you? where should I apply ? =D

Comment: by experts i mean to those that have some experience :D
I have done a couple of websites but where hosted on my machine...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developing on a local server should be faster since you can preview all the changes "live", without uploading the updated files to the hosted server. So yeah, I'd recommend working locally. I use Wamp myself.

As for the database, you can export it in PHPMyAdmin (ships with Wamp). It should generate a gigantic query (a set of queries, actually), which you can then execute on your site to create the tables and fill them with content.

Comment: Also note that if you (the original poster) decide to add a new table to your database later, you can export *just that table* and import it into your online database - you needn't drop & import the entire database, or even manually configure a new table online. Basic info, yes, but this dude seems pretty basic! :-)

Comment: True, true. For instance, I sometimes do that to sync the registered users between my two Drupal sites :).

Answer (score 5):

linky:

- [**PHP 101: PHP For the Absolute
  Beginner**](http://devzone.zend.com/article/627)
- [**W3Schools**](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/DEfaULT.asP)
- [**Database-Driven Web Site Using PHP
  and MySQL**](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/ddws/index.html)
- [**PHP/MySQL Tutorial**](http://www.freewebmasterhelp.com/tutorials/phpmysql)

**EDIT:**

---

**About Development Servers:**

your Webhost is never bothered about how you develop your application, neither thay can provide or will ever provide development tools, technologies or space for this purpose. They only [**host**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_hosting_service) your Application. So, It is your problem

> "Shall I develop it on my machine at
> home" ?

Yes, because it is the only option you have if you want to do it yourself. The best way to do this is (IMHO), develop the application on your `development machine`, and `test` it on a another machine (`server`) with the `specification`, `nearest` to the one your `commercial webhost` has.

Best of luck

Comment: thanks asad ... i am sure this manual will be very useful! :D ... but i did not found a solution on my question ... (re the VPS)

Answer (score 2):

Best method is to keep two servers.  One is your production environment (the purchased one mounted in some rack somewhere).  The second is your development environment (virtual machine running Linux, basically a copy of the production server).

You should be doing your development at home using whatever editor/IDE makes you happy (I recommend PHPDesigner).  MySQL Workbench works great for creating/editing your MySQL database.

Copying changes over is as easy as rsync for the files and MySQL Table Export for the tables.

I also recommend running a SubVersion server on the Development machine, so you can keep dated revisions of your work (even if you are doing it alone).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your home setup. There is a way to export MySQL DBs, so you'll be able to transfer the database if that's the route you take. Having something like PHPMyAdmin makes this a lot simpler (comes default in XAMPP, which I would recommend using for a home server if you haven't set one up already).